# Reading binary data from stdin

Tags: python, python-2.x

Is it possible to read stdin as binary data in Python 2.6?  If so, how?

I see in the [Python 3.1 documentation](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/sys.html) that this is fairly simple, but the facilities for doing this in 2.6 don't seem to be there.

If the methods described in 3.1 aren't available, is there a way to close stdin and reopen in in binary mode?

Just to be clear, I am using 'type' in a MS-DOS shell to pipe the contents of a binary file to my python code.  This should be the equivalent of a Unix 'cat' command, as far as I understand.  But when I test this out, I always get one byte less than the expected file size.

---

The reason I'm going the Java/JAR/Jython route is because one of my main external libraries is only available as a Java JAR.  But unfortunately, I had started my work as Python.  It might have been easier to convert my code over to Java a while ago, but since this stuff was all supposed to be compatible, I figured I would try trucking through it and prove it could be done.

In case anyone was wondering, this is also related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827771/packaging-and-deploying-a-jython-program-from-eclipse) I asked a few days ago.

Some of was answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252965/distributing-my-python-scripts-as-jars-with-jython).

So I'll try to update my original question with some notes on what I have figured out so far.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the [`-u` command line switch](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u) to force Python 2 to treat stdin, stdout and stderr as binary unbuffered streams.

```
C:> type mydoc.txt | python.exe -u myscript.py
```

Comment: I have tested this with 'type' and it appears to work.  That is, if I leave out the -u flag, I get one fewer character per line.

Comment: Cool.  Thanks for the test.

So, just because I like you so much, any idea how to pass the '-u' option through the JarRunner.java class that is used to fire off Jython through an executable JAR file?

I know.  I never do anything the easy way.

Comment: According to docs, setting the PYTHONUNBUFFERED environment variable will have the same effect.  Not sure if that helps.

Comment: Even easier, it appears that all you need to do is:

sys.stdin = os.fdopen(sys.stdin.fileno(), 'rb', 0)

That will reopen the fd in unbuffered 'binary' mode.

Comment: @thebeav: Oddly enough that doesn't work on my system.  I don't know if that's because I'm using CPython instead of Jython, or if it's because I'm running Windows XP Pro, and "type" behaves differently, or its because there is a magnetic anomaly in the Manassas area that makes computers do different things.

FWIW, I tried a number of ways to get Python to change the file mode after the interpreter had started, including accessing the C runtime's "setmode" function via ctypes.  Nothing works for me.

Comment: Uh-oh.  I smell a portability issue.  Thanks for the info.  I guess I'm going to have to do some fairly rigorous testing on multiple platforms.  I hope this doesn't have to do with the JVM in use.

Answer (score 30):

From the docs (see [here](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/sys.html#sys.stdin)):

> The standard streams are in text mode
>   by default. To write or read binary
>   data to these, use the underlying
>   binary buffer. For example, to write
>   bytes to stdout, use
>   `sys.stdout.buffer.write(b'abc')`.

But, as in the accepted answer, invoking python with a `-u` is another option which forces stdin, stdout and stderr to be totally unbuffered. See the python(1) manpage for details.

See the [documentation on `io`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.detach) for more information on text buffering, and use `sys.stdin.detach()` to disable buffering from within Python.

Comment: that doc leads to py3k docs, not what the OP wants to deal with.

Comment: I've tried `-u` with Python v3.2.5 but it did nothing useful. But using `sys.stdout.buffer` works pretty well though on Python 2.7.8 there is no such feature.

Comment: The OP's question was about Python 2.6.

Answer (score 24):

Here is the final cut for Linux/Windows Python 2/3 compatible code to read data from stdin without corruption:

```
import sys

PY3K = sys.version_info >= (3, 0)

if PY3K:
    source = sys.stdin.buffer
else:
    # Python 2 on Windows opens sys.stdin in text mode, and
    # binary data that read from it becomes corrupted on \r\n
    if sys.platform == "win32":
        # set sys.stdin to binary mode
        import os, msvcrt
        msvcrt.setmode(sys.stdin.fileno(), os.O_BINARY)
    source = sys.stdin

b = source.read()
```

Answer (score 9):

If you still need this...
This simple test i've used to read binary file that contains 0x1A character in between

```
import os, sys, msvcrt

msvcrt.setmode (sys.stdin.fileno(), os.O_BINARY)
s = sys.stdin.read()
print len (s)
```

My test file data was:

```
0x23, 0x1A, 0x45
```

Without setting stdin to binary mode this test prints 1 as soon it treats 0x1A as EOF.
Of course it works on windows only, because depends on msvcrt module.

Comment: But Windows is the only system where most people will run into a problem, so this should be an acceptable solution.

Comment: This is the correct solution for Python 2 to retrieve the raw bytes from stdin on Windows. On Unix, there is no difference between binary and normal mode. See this thread: http://code.activestate.com/lists/python-list/20426/ (re-opening stdin in raw (binary) mode?)

Comment: I was getting a `ValueError: insecure string pickle` exception on Windows when trying to un`pickle` data that had been written to `stdout` in one process which was being piped into another. The solution turned out to be adding a `msvcrt.setmode(sys.stdout.fileno(), os.O_BINARY)` in the process that wrote the data.

Answer (score 3):

You can perform an unbuffered read with:

`os.read(0, bytes_to_read)`

with 0 being the file descriptor for stdin

Answer (score 0):

To read binary data from stdin (in Python 2.4–2.7, 3.0–, both Unix and Windows), do this:

```py
import os, sys
if sys.platform.startswith('win'):
    try:
        __import__('msvcrt').setmode(sys.stdout.fileno(), os.O_BINARY)
    except ImportError:
        pass
sys.stdin = os.fdopen(sys.stdin.fileno(), 'rb')
...
print(sys.stdin.read(4096))
```

To read binary data from stdin, without modifying `sys.stdin` (in Python 2.4–2.7, 3.0–, both Unix and Windows), do this:

```py
import os, sys
f = os.fdopen(os.dup(sys.stdin.fileno()), 'rb')
if sys.platform.startswith('win'):
    try:
        __import__('msvcrt').setmode(f.fileno(), os.O_BINARY)
    except ImportError:
        pass
...
print(f.read(4096))
```

To read binary data unbuffered (i.e. as soon as it is available to the Python process) from a file object, while putting the underlying file descriptor to binary mode, do this (in Python 2.4–2.7, 3.0–, both Unix and Windows):

```py
import os, sys
f = sys.stdin  # Or anything other file object.
if sys.platform.startswith('win'):
    try:
        __import__('msvcrt').setmode(f.fileno(), os.O_BINARY)
    except ImportError:
        pass
...
print(os.read(f.fileno(), 4096))
```

For unbuffered binary reads, it's tempting to do `f = os.fdopen(f.fileno(), 'rb', 0)`, but in Python 2.x it doesn't make the read (i.e. `f.read(4096)`) unbuffered, it would still wait indefinitely for more input until the 4096 bytes are filled or EOF is reached.

Answer (score -3):

```
import sys

data = sys.stdin.read(10) # Read 10 bytes from stdin
```

If you need to interpret binary data, use the `struct` module.

Comment: If I then call sys.stdin.read() with no parameter, it should read all the binary data that was piped in, correct?  How then do I determine the length correctly?  len(data) returns the incorrect value if the last byte of the data was a zero.  How do you check and correct for this situation?

Comment: `len` counts the \x00 characters in the string. Python does not have null terminated strings. `len("Hello\x00") == 6`

Comment: I wonder then if it might be the 'type' command from the MS-DOS shell that is causing the loss of the final byte?  I guess I will have to test the equivalent on Linux.  Thanks.

Comment: I think this answer misses the point of the question: if the stream is in "text" mode, the results from `read()` might be different than if the stream is in "binary" mode.

Comment: It might corrupt input stream on Windows e.g., `'\r\n'` -> `'\n'`. Also, on Python 3 `sys.stdin.read()` returns Unicode strings e.g., `b'\xf0\x9f\x96\x96'` -> `'\U0001f596'` (4 bytes -> 1 chararcter). It is undesirable behaviour if input is not text.