# Read stdin as binary

Tags: python, stdin

I have code that opens and reads a file from binary.

```
with open (file, mode="rb") as myfile:
    message_string=myfile.read()
    myfile.close
```

I now need to do the same thing reading from stdin.  But I can't figure out how to read binary.

The error says byte strings only.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 88):

In Python 3, if you want to read binary data from `stdin`, you need to use its `buffer` attribute:

```
import sys

data = sys.stdin.buffer.read()
```

On Python 2, `sys.stdin.read()` already returns a byte string; there is no need to use `buffer`.

Comment: Not true about Python 2. It reads in text mode by default. E.g. on Windows a file like "a\r\nb" fed into stdin will appear as "a\nb". See here for solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850893/reading-binary-data-from-stdin

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38939320/239247 for proper solution on Windows.

Comment: @EvgeniSergeev Did you actually try it? `$ printf "a\r\nb\rc\r" | python2.7 -c 'import sys; print(sys.stdin.readlines())'` produces `['a\r\n', 'b\rc\r']`

Comment: @Clément: They said "on Windows". `$` suggests you aren't running it on Windows. (Unless you're using the Windows Subsystem for Linux thing, which for these purposes we can consider to be not-Windows.)