# Python 2.7 - How to programmatically read binary data from stdin

Tags: python, python-2.7, input, binary

I'd like to be able to read binary data from stdin with python.

However, when I use `input = sys.stdin.buffer.read()`, I get the error that `AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'buffer'`.  This seems strange because the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdin) say that I should be able to use the underlying buffer object - how can I fix / work around this?

Notes:  I've checked out the [last time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850893/reading-binary-data-from-stdin) this was asked, but the answers there are all either "use -u", "use buffer" (which I'm trying), or something about reading from files.  The first and last don't help because I have no control over the users of this program (so I can't tell them to use particular arguments) and because this is stdin - not files.

Comment: You are reading the documentation for Python 3, but using Python 2.

Comment: You can just use `sys.stdin.read()`. It's already a binary stream.

Comment: This solution was mentiond in the comments of the question you linked to: `sys.stdin = os.fdopen(sys.stdin.fileno(), 'rb', 0)`

Comment: @tavnab sure, but that is reading in text mode, which if that's the case, doesn't the OP really just want `raw_input`? Have I just not slept enough?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga you're right, it's opened in text mode by default. The `-u` would still be needed to read it in unbuffered & binary mode. If the OP's expecting to read unbuffered (i.e. no waiting for the newline) from the keyboard though (e.g. writing a game), they'll probably also need to enable "raw" mode on the tty

Comment: @tavnab or use `os.fdopen(sys.stdin.fileno(), 'rb', 0)` buy I suspect the OP really just wants raw_input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the buffer for python2:

```
import sys

input = sys.stdin.read()
```

Comment: Thank you!  I thought I'd have to do something special for this and I am pleasantly surprised that that was not the case.