# Python 2.7 - How to preserve binary data read from stdin

Tags: python, python-2.7, input, binary, stdin

I'd like to be able to read binary data from stdin and have it preserved as binary data (i.e. no coercion to string as sys.stdin.read does). How can I do this with Python 2.7?

Edit:  The answers given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850893/reading-binary-data-from-stdin), are not suitable for the following reasons:

- Using the extension "-u" will not work because I have no control over how users interact with the program.
- Using sys.stdin.read will not work because that function coerces the input to a string - I would like for it to remain as bytes.
- Using "msvcrt.setmode (sys.stdin.fileno(), os.O_BINARY)" will not work because that is a windows-specific solution and I'd like this to be cross-platform.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading binary data from stdin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850893/reading-binary-data-from-stdin)

Comment: Abdou, this question is different from that one for the reasons given in the edit.

Comment: Why can't you just use `msvcrt.setmode` on Windows and do nothing on other platforms?

Comment: Sure, but how do you do it on other platforms?

Comment: This is a good question that deserves an answer.

Comment: @Everyone_Else: Most other platforms are binary by default, there is nothing to do.