# Python: piping pcap file to stdout gives error

Tags: python, pipe, stdout, pcap

I am trying to pipe the output of `xz` to a custom python script:

```
xz -cd file.pcap.xz | myscripy.py
```

However, I get an error when the script attempts to run this line:

```
  #!/usr/bin/env python2.7
from __future__ import print_function

import pcap
import io
STDIN_ALIAS = '/proc/self/fd/0' 

pcap.pcap(io.open(STDIN_ALIAS, 'r'))
```

and received an error

```
    pcap.pcap(io.open(STDIN_ALIAS, 'r'))
  File "pcap.pyx", line 196, in pcap.pcap.__init__
TypeError: expected string or Unicode object, _io.TextIOWrapper found
```

I am on Ubuntu 18.04 and running under python 2.7.

Comment: Given the traceback, this must be [`pypcap` version 1.1.5](https://github.com/pynetwork/pypcap), as corroborated by the [available Ubuntu package for 18.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/python-pypcap)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use Python to pass in packets from a file to `pcap.pcap()`. The [`pypcap` library](https://github.com/pynetwork/pypcap) you are using is a thin wrapper around the [`pcap_open_offline()`](https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap_open_offline.3pcap.html) and [`pcap_create()`](https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap_create.3pcap.html) C functions, and offers no facilities for passing in a Python file object. This wrapper *only* accepts a filename or a network interface name, nothing else.

The `pcap_open_offline()` function does accept `-` as an alias for `stdin`, so just pass that in directly:

```
import pcap

sniffer = pcap.pcap('-')
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message already tell you what happened. You need a string to the `pcap()` function, not a file object. To fix this, try

```
pcap.pcap(io.open(STDIN_ALIAS, 'r').read())
```

But I am not sure this will work as your file might be binary instead of text. In such case, you may want to open with `'rb'` instead of `'r'` flag, and do some conversion afterwards (especially if you use Python 3 instead of Python 2.7).

I see another issue: your code is not portable as it depends on this:

```
STDIN_ALIAS = '/proc/self/fd/0'
```

A pythonic way to read the stdin is the follows (see  [Reading binary data from stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850893/reading-binary-data-from-stdin))

```
import sys
string = sys.stdin.read()
```

Comment: i tried `pcap.pcap(io.open(STDIN_ALIAS, 'r').read())` it gave an error :
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xb2 in position 2: invalid start byte'

i tried `pcap.pcap(io.open(STDIN_ALIAS, 'rb').read())` it gave an error :
`OSError: M<��: You don't have permission to capture on that device (socket: Operation not permitted)`

Comment: You can't pass packets to the `pcap.pcap()` class; it only accepts a filename or a network interface. Luckily, the filename `-` is accepted to refer to stdin.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried upgrading PyPcap to work on Python 3? This could help, since Unicode handling is a lot cleaner and less prone to surprises on Python 3. The appropriate package is available, at least on Debian (and probably derived distros as well). Look for: python3-pypcap.

Comment: cant find them via apt-get

Comment: This isn't a Unicode issue, as pcap simply can't be passed an open file object, not via the Python wrapper at any rate. This applies to both Python 2 and Python 3, the library is the same.