# How to read binary data via pipe in python

Tags: python

What do I need do to make sure the data is read as binary and not text
when i do

```
cat binfile | myscript.py
```

reads as text mode I need binary mode?

```
data = sys.stdin.read
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading binary data from stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850893/reading-binary-data-from-stdin)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the latest version of Python, that you're looking for is:

```
sys.stdin.buffer.read()
```

Note: You must use `help(sys.__stdin__)` in interactive mode. This is because you can't use the normal `stdin` in interactive mode. `sys.stdin.buffer` simply doesn't exist in interactive mode.

Comment: I did that and get AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'buffer'

Comment: What version of python are you using (`python -V` to check)

Comment: Python 2.7.5
Actualy this worked. sys.stdin.read(). I tested on a file with just this

Comment: I don't know how Python 2 work in this case but Python 3 would wait indefinitely for a `\n` and if you send binary data, the wait can be long.