# Python: Reading and Writing to a binary file in Powershell from stdin

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell, stdout, stdin

I have the following two programs written in Python

```
# cat.py
import sys

filename = sys.argv[1]

with open(filename, "rb") as f:
    while c := f.read(1024 * 1024):
        sys.stdout.buffer.write(c)
```

This program reads a file and outputs it as a binary to stdout.

The following program is meant to read the data and print it as bytes.

```
import sys
import io
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(sys.stdin.buffer.read(io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE))
```

However I do not get the file contents in this case. If I run this under Linux I do get the exact contents however if I run this in windows I do not:

```
python cat.py .\inputs\input.bin | python main.py
```

Output on Windows (running under pwsh.exe):

```
0x3
0xc2
0xb7
0x55
0x12
0x20
0x66
0x67
0x50
0xc3
0x9e
0xc2
0xbd
0xd
0xa
```

Output on Linux (This is correct):

```
0x3
0xfa
0x55
0x12
0x20
0x66
0x67
0x50
0xe8
0xab
```

Any ideas why this may be the case? Is it newline endings or something like that?

Also, in cat.py if I write to a file rather than stdout I do get the correct contents written to the file.

---

Update:

Okay, I have narrowed it down to it being a powershell issue. If i run this in cmd.exe I do not have any issues, however, if I run it under powershell I do.

Comment: Are we talking Python3 or Python2?

Comment: Sorry, I didnt mention, I was using Python 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that there are different encodings set up for both command lines which can results in a different data streams.

Unfortunately, even if you read in from stdin as binary, it has to go through the commandline and there typically is a system-wide encoding setting that affects it.

There is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38939320/6573902) that should help resolving this issue.

Comment: I did have a look at the answer, it does mention using sys.stdin.buffer and sys.stdout.buffer which I am doing.

Comment: It has to do with the system-wide encoding, even though both are using the same encoding, powershell corrupts it as it misinterprets the encoding from the python application. Pythons default of UTF-8 is not understood by powershell.
https://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2010/05/26/handling-native-exe-output-encoding-in-utf8-with-no-bom/