# Packaging Jython with Modules for Easy Installation

Tags: python, maven, jython, packaging, apache-pig

I've just built a Jython project that uses both some Python module imports and some Java jars. On my own computer, since I just wanted the thing done, I've gotten things to work in a very hacky way by hardcoding sys.path and installing every module and jar I wanted separately. This is definitely not something I want to keep for a release version. I've read about being able to package everything up into one standalone Jython jar, and that sounds pretty good to me. Is there any reason I shouldn't do this? If not, is there a guide on the best way to do this someone can point me to? I'm running the whole thing through PIG, so having a callable Jython jar would be ideal.

I know some similar questions to this already exist on SO, but the answers to those seem pretty old, and the documentation given (for MavenJython, for example) is pretty poor. I've already looked at [MavenJython](http://mavenjython.sourceforge.net/), and [Jip](https://github.com/sunng87/jip), but I can't really decide between the two, and I'm not really finding sufficient information for either. An ideal answer to this question what I should use, why I should use it, and give a brief demo of how one would use it. A link to any of those would also be awesome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please elaborate on how the MavenJython documentation can be improved. Things have not changed since 2011 (you probably [have seen this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660054/using-jython-with-maven/7078178#7078178)), which is not that long ago.  There is the website, but as a programmer you probably just want to read the source code of the [jython-compile-maven-plugin-test](https://sourceforge.net/p/mavenjython/code/ci/HEAD/tree/python-test-maven-plugin-test/) project, which is only 200 lines of code. It is a good idea to use this package as a starting point for your own project.

### Distribution philosophies

The way Java software distribution (and Windows software distribution) usually works is that you package everything you need. So yes, a standalone Jython jar would be appropriate. The drawback is that every software may use a different Jython version, the benefit being that this might be what you want (updates may break things). This is the MavenJython approach too, packaging everything in the correct versions.

Python and Linux software distribution just installs packages, checking compatibility at install time. This is the jip approach, which assumes you already have Jython, and whoever installs software will resolve compability issues by installing the correct versions.

### Differences

I can not say much about jip though, I have not used it. From what I see in the demos jip is meant to provide Python packages access to Maven Java libraries. It also seems to be capable of producing maven packages from Jython code. So you can probably achieve your goal using either MavenJython or jip. Just try.

The deliverables built using MavenJython distribute Jython, while jip does not.

- If you want to instruct programmers who already use jython and are unfamiliar with Maven, who want to use your library to fetch your jython library package, jip might be the way to go.
- If you want to write Jython libraries for programmers and distribute them, you can use either MavenJython or jip.
- If you have a software package that is going to end up as a deliverable to customers, which happens to also use Jython code and Jython packages, perhaps also providing in-program scripting to the user, go with MavenJython. It allows you to create a standalone executable.

### Pig use case

For running jython through pig it is enough to install jython and put the jython sources in your path -- see the [embed python section of the pig manual](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/cont.html#embed-python). jip can be appropriate for installing jython packages locally, but is not necessary if you  only want to run your code. If you however want to distribute software which uses pig, and install pig, jython and your code on a clients computer, MavenJython can do that for you.