# Packaging Jython project into Jar with/without PyDev

Tags: eclipse, jar, pydev, jython

I am using PyDev in Eclipse to write my jython project. In this project I am using some external jar files (like log4j). Now that I am done I would like to export my work as a single executable jar file. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Maybe this can help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827771/packaging-and-deploying-a-jython-program-from-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct support in PyDev to do that.

Your best choice is probably using maven: http://maven.apache.org/ or ant: http://ant.apache.org/ to do that.

Comment: Did you (or anyone else) actually try that? I cannot apply maven on a PyDev project in Eclipse.
Is it possible to provide steps if you have tried maven or ant on top of PyDev?

Comment: No, I haven't, but you should not be restricted to PyDev here... What you should look is how to create a bundle for a Jython project -- as  if it was in the filesystem without any IDE integration.