# Making Double-Clickable Jython .jars

Tags: java, python, jar, jython

I have been teaching myself Jython, and try as I might I cannot compile a script as a double-clickable .jar.

I have made a directory 'C:\Folder'. In it there is:

- a copy of the standalone jython.jar,
- a copy of the Lib folder from the Jython directory,
- file.py, a Jython script that draws a Swing frame with a label, and
- a copy of the 7-Zip command line tool (7za) for zipping.

I have looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252965/distributing-my-python-scripts-as-jars-with-jython), [here](http://wiki.python.org/jython/JythonFaq/DistributingJythonScripts), [here](http://guzdial.cc.gatech.edu/cs6452/34), and a few other places, and the furthest I've gotten is a .jar that runs with:

```
java -jar jython.jar -jar jython.jar arg1 arg2
```

Which I get by renaming 'file.py' to '__run__.py' and zipping it and 'Lib' into 'jython.jar'.

I would, however, love to be able to skip the command line all together. 
So if anyone would walk me through the commands (I'm using Windows 7) to compile those into a double-clickable jar (let me know what else I may need, too) it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do normal JARs open with Java?  If not, you just need to add the file association (via the "Open With" dialog).

Comment: Oh geez, _SO_ sorry. I'd been checking the post via the profile page so I wouldn't bump the views and didn't see the alert. I don't have any JARs on hand but the Open With window says 'Java Platform SE binary' for the ones I've made.

Comment: The second link you've got there, did you use the method in section 8 (i.e., 'What's a really easy way...')? That's the method I've used and I haven't had any problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a folder with:

- a copy of the standalone jython.jar,
- a copy of the Lib folder from the Jython directory,
- file.py, a Jython script ..

you can use [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) to build an .exe on windows

have a look at the docs on [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/)