# Load Python C Extension DLL using System.loadLibrary

Tags: java, python, windows, python-2.7

I have a [Python C Extension DLL](http://docs.python.org/2/extending/windows.html) with extension [pyd](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/windows.html#is-a-pyd-file-the-same-as-a-dll), that I would like to load in Java through [System.loadLibrary](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#loadLibrary%28java.lang.String%29)  on windows.
It seems that there is no way to load a dll with an extension different from *.dll.

Is there any suggested approach to overcome this issue?

**Use Case**

I am planning to embed Python in Java. I created an extension dll which I was loading in JAVA, using JNI to communicate with the extension dll which in turn interacts with the Python Runtime Environment to execute the Python Statements

```
_____                     _____          _____
| J | System.loadLibrary  |   |          | P |
| A |-------------------->| P |          | Y |
| V |                     | Y |<-------->| T |
| A |       JNI           | D |          | H |
|___|<------------------->|___|          | O |
                                         | N |
                                         |___|
```

Comment: The only thing I can think of would be to either rename the file so it has a `.dll` extension, or create a copy with a `.dll` extension. However, it seems a bit strange to load a `.pyd` in Java. What's the use-case?

Comment: @Aya: Use case updated in the Question

Comment: @downvoter: Please explain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using  [System.load()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#load%28java.lang.String%29) instead?  You can specify whatever file name you want, but the downside is that you need the complete path to the .pyd file.

---

It is not hard to search the paths that a .dll would be loaded from:

```
for (String s: System.getProperty("java.library.path").split(";")) {
    String pydName = s + "/mypythonlib.pyd";
    File pydFile = new File(pydName);
    if (pydFile.exists()) {
        System.load(pydName);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: `downside is that you need the complete path to the .pyd file.`, so I didn't try

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Can you please explain how it answers the question?

Comment: Well, how about you explain why it fails to answer the question. Anyway, if you want to embed Python, why don't you do that. All the functions you need are found in `pythonXX.dll`. I don't see why you would load a .pyd in Java. What can Java do with it? A .pyd file is for consumption by the Python runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you just want to run Python code in Java, then [Jython](http://www.jython.org/) will let you compile Python source code into Java `.class` bytecode, but you won't be able to use any CPython functionality which uses extension modules.

If you really need to embed CPython in Java, then 'importing' a `.pyd` file isn't going to help you. A `.pyd` will only function correctly if the Python interpreter has already been initialized will a call to `Py_Initialize()`.

What you need to do is look at the CPython [embedding docs](http://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html), and use JNI to call the underlying CPython functions as per the examples in those docs.

**Update**

It sounds like what you have is a single `.dll` file which acts as an extension module, but also exposes some symbols you're using to embed Python in Java. If you never plan to import it in CPython, then just rename it to `.dll`.

If you do need to import it in CPython, then you probably ought to split the functionality into two separate `.dll` files - one which you use in the JNI embedding, and the other which just acts as an extension module.

Comment: Jython unfortunately has lots of limitation esp when trying to use ctypes which would in-turn have issues importing lot of libraries which uses ctypes. And secondly the linked document is very generic and part of it I did undertook to make the interface between C and Python work. Moreover as you mentioned in the comment, when I rename `pyd` to `dll` it works like charm. So the only part which is creating trouble is the one mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Abhijit It almost sounds like your `.pyd` file is actually exposing more methods than is required for it to function as a `.pyd`. Does it even expose the symbols necessary for it to be imported in CPython?

Comment: I am currently not planning to import in Python directly but theoretically I can, bit then again `Does it even expose the symbols necessary for it to be imported in CPython`, how would it impact my design decision? Do you wan't to infer that I shouldn't make it pyd in the first instance? Candidly speaking, I am too contemplating this, but that would create another issue, esp when building pyd through distutil which by default generates a pyd rather than dll.

Comment: @Abhijit See updated answer, but it's getting to the point where I'm having to speculate too much as to the contents of the `.pyd` file, so it might help to include some of the source code, most notably for the symbols which are `dllexport`ed.

Answer (score 1):

See [Calling Python in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898765/calling-python-in-java). Basically, you use either `org.python.util.PythonInterpreter` to call Python or Jython. Another possible solution is to use a UNIX-style .so file. Yet another choice may be to use get the current path, merge it with the name of the .pyd file, and use System.load() as specified by Markku K.

Comment: Please refer the comment to @Aya's answer to understand why Jython would not work for me.

Comment: @Abhijit: Your best option is probably to use `System.load()` like this: 1.Get the current directory(`System.getProperty("user.dir")`). 2.Combine the current directory with the name of the library(`full_path = current_dir + name_of_module`). 3.Load the full path using `System.load()`.