# Simple and effective way to call Python from Java

Tags: java, python, jython, cython, jna

I have a couple of python scripts whose methods I'd like to access from Java. These functions take a string as a parameter and also return a string. What would be a simple and effective way to do that?

My python codes don't run under jython. With jython, I get loads of errors for simple things like:

> 'with' will become a reserved keyword in Python 2.6

However, I am able to create .so objects using cython. Could that be used from Java?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898765/calling-python-in-java?

Comment: I don't this question has been satisfactorily answered there :/

Comment: You need to post your code and the specific error please :)

Comment: If your python code does not run under jython, why do you think there is a "simple and effective" way to do it?

Comment: @Remolten Edited my question to include the errors.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I was hoping I could do that since it works fine with cython.

Comment: Is it possible that cython is using an interpreter with a grammar of >= 2.6 and jython is using a grammar of < 2.6? This seems like the bigger issue here.

Comment: I think you are correct, I just checked cython is using 2.6.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to wrap the functions in a command line executable that outputs the desired result. Then you can use [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) to call the script and get the output.

Comment: Is there no neater way to do this?