# Calling Python program from Java

Tags: java, python

I have a console application developed in C Python language. I need to call this program function from my java code. Also, I need to pass some arguments such as List<> to the main function once it is called. I have researched a found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898765/calling-python-in-java) link, but it is for a J Python code. Do we have a similar facility for C Python?

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

public class SystemCall{

        private static Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(SystemCall.class);

    public static int execute(String command) {
        int result = 0;
        if (command == null){
                throw new RuntimeException("harness command is null");
        }
        Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();

        try {
            Process p = r.exec(command);
            try {
                if (p.waitFor() != 0) {
                    result = p.exitValue();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                logger.error("System call interupted.", e);
                //TODO
            } finally {
                //TODO
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.error("IO error in system call.", e);
                //TODO
        }
        return result;
     }
 }
```