# Can I use C++ or Python in Eclipse plugin?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I need an Eclipse plugin which will  use some API written in python or C++.

Is it possible to write an eclipse plugin using one of these languages, or I should use something like JNI to call the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse plugins must be written in Java.

To use C/C++ code you would have to use JNI.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8898765/2670892) covers calling python from Java.