# How to call Python function from Java code without use of Jython

Tags: java, python, numpy

I am trying to call my Python code from Java code without use of Jython, as my code contains Numpy, Scipy and other modules which are not available on Jython, moreover I want to create an API of my Python code for Java.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898765/calling-python-in-java

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do you want them to run in two different processes?
If yes, then you can consider some inter process communication like socket programming.