# executing python code throught java

Tags: java, python, linux, shell

is there a way to execute python through java, like

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sudo python -c 'print(\"Test\")'");
```

I could swear it worked last night...

Thanks.

Comment: You can use Jython. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898765/calling-python-in-java

Comment: maybe avoid `sudo` in the first place...