# How to obtain one's xbox live service token?

Tags: python-3.x, http, xbox-live

I'm trying to replicate a http request to connect to a minecraft realm like the ones shown here https://wiki.vg/Bedrock_Realms#Endpoints using python. However, I don't understand what an Xbox live service token is. There is almost nothing about it that I could find online. What is this token and how do I obtain it? Is replicating those requests possible? Please let me know.

Comment: I have the same question, and unfortunately the same results so far.

Comment: The header listed there begins with `Authorization: XBL3.0 `. This is documented at [Xbox Live / EDS Authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/gaming/xbox-live/api-ref/xbox-live-rest/additional/edsauthorization#30-tokens-multiuser-vs-single-user) and you can see that [OpenXbox implements it here](https://github.com/OpenXbox/xbox-webapi-python/blob/v2.0.10/xbox/webapi/authentication/models.py#L79-L81). Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65693218/1874170)