# Can we write our agent in python in UnetStack?

Tags: unetstack

I am writing a custom `phy` agent in `UnetStack`. I knew we can use `Groovy`, `Java`, `Julia` or `C`, Can i use `python` to write my agent ? If yes, What should i take care of and is there specific skeleton for it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fjåge only supports Groovy and Java agents out of the box, but supports only the Gateway API for Python, Julia, C, etc. An alpha version of Julia agent support is already available, but even without that, one can call Julia from Groovy agents. The [Blog article: Harnessing the power of Julia in UnetStack — Part II](https://blog.unetstack.net/custom-phy-in-julia) covers how a custom PHY can be written using a Groovy agent, with all the signal processing in Julia.

You could do pretty much the same with Python, calling your Python code from a Java/Groovy agent. I have not tried doing this, but the basic idea is the same as what we do with Julia in the blog, and shouldn't be too hard to get to work. You can check out [Java2Python](https://pythonhosted.org/javabridge/java2python.html) and/or [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898765/calling-python-in-java) as a starting point.