# Convert Jython scripts to .jar file

Tags: java, python, jar, zip, jython

I have been trying to convert jython scripts to .jar file. I followed,

[Distributing my Python scripts as JAR files with Jython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252965/distributing-my-python-scripts-as-jars-with-jython)

The link above and also the Jython wiki link shown inside it use a command line script called, "zip". Its like =>  zip myapp.jar Lib

and so. I am on windows machine, so I couldn't find any script as "zip" on my command line, may be its a Linux script. Help me to do it in windows machine

Second is I have few external .jar's that are used in my jython scripts, for this the above link says to use manifest. But I want to package all external jars into single myapp.jar(for example) file to be running. Just like java -jar myapp.jar, so is there any way to package external jars also?

So please help me resolve this

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jar` command to add files to `.jar` archive. Just like:

```
jar uvf jythonlib.jar Lib
```

Use `jar` to see help with options and examples of usage.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, the code `zip -r jythonlib.jar Lib` and `zip myapp.jar Lib/showobjs.py`, just add files to a jar archive. The `zip` program is a specific tool to do this, but it is not the only one. On windows, I would recommend using [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) to create the jar. Rather than `zip -r jythonlib.jar Lib`, open a new 7-zip window, create a new archive (zip protocol) called `jythonlib.jar` and add the folder called `Lib` which resides in $JYHTON_HOME. Then continue with the guide and when you get to `zip myapp.jar Lib/showobjs.py`, simply drag and drop the file called `showobjs.py` into the existing 7-zip window. This should add the file to the archive.