# Tkinter executable seen as virus

Tags: python, tkinter, exe, virus

Any tkinter executable I make is seen as a virus.
Across multiple machines and various different virus scanners.

When making the executable I use:

```
pyinstaller -w --onefile test.py
```

If I add a shell command to the pyinstaller it is NOT seen as a virus.

```
pyinstaller --onefile test.py
```

Does anyone know why this is happening ?

Im using Python 3.8.1 - 32 bit.
My operating system is Windows 10 64-bit

Comment: What kind of "virus" is it detecting? Can you give a screenshot or paste the text report of the "virus"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Virus warnings after trying to run .py program converted to an .exe file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54156685/virus-warnings-after-trying-to-run-py-program-converted-to-an-exe-file)

Comment: @SyntaxVoidsupportsMonica 
It doesn't see it as any specific virus.
It says stuff like: Malicious behavior blocked or Infected file detected.
In quarantine its labeled as Malware

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43777106/program-made-with-pyinstaller-now-seen-as-a-trojan-horse-by-avg/62928363#62928363