# Pyinstaller convert to EXE Virus detecting

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, pyinstaller, exe

Is there anyway to create .exe and share to friends.
I am not sure why there are 1 million videos on how to converted .exe, even when sometime it gets auto deleted in windows. Gmail is not allowing it to send to anyone.

Comment: You should refer to this Question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54156685/virus-warnings-after-trying-to-run-py-program-converted-to-an-exe-file

Comment: Some virus checkers (for example Windows Defender) report a false positive for some (not all) executables constructed by `pyinstaller`. It's a bug in the virus checker but you won't find it easy to get it fixed. All you can do is futz with the file until it no longer matches the virus signature that the virus checker is looking for. For one project of mine, switching it from Python 3.9 to Python 3.8 did the trick. But because it's a bug, there is no guarantee that will work for you. There is no accounting for bugs.

Comment: Problem is different, I have good experience in other language as well.
This file and .exe is working perfectly in my system. I cant share it, one way to solve it provide signature and version using third party tool.
If I provide .py to other user then that person should be using python and know how to run. This is quite weird.

So I created a exe for one of my client but I spent 7 hours to looking at all solutions but none of them was working. Even converting into .jar you need to to have Java run time installed, this is same as installing python.
I am looking at easy solution for this.