# how to turn python to .jar

Tags: python, jar

I don't know how to turn my python script to a .jar file

```
import time
import keyboard
import pyautogui


pyautogui.click(100, 1060, duration=0.5)
pyautogui.hotkey('esc')
pyautogui.keyDown('o')

for number in range(1000):
    if keyboard.is_pressed('j'):
        break
    pyautogui.keyDown('d')
    time.sleep(72.3)
    pyautogui.keyUp('d')
    pyautogui.keyDown('a')
    time.sleep(72.3)
    pyautogui.keyUp('a')
```

i can't figure out how to have this in a .jar file

Comment: Do the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252965/distributing-my-python-scripts-as-jar-files-with-jython) help at all?

Comment: Why at all `.jar` ?

Comment: Install PyInstaller
pyinstaller --onefile thisscript.py
then get JarSplice   from 
https://sourceforge.net/projects/jarsplice/